# How to run code after all angularjs child controllers have been initialized?

Tags: angularjs

Child controllers can use `$scope.$emit` to send values to their parent controller (or access the parent's scope directly), but how can we know when all children are present?

http://jsfiddle.net/37uL4/

Comment: Why don't you then $emit from every child?

Answer (score 1):

It can be done with promises. You will have to create a promise per expected controller, resolve it when you get the corresponding message, and trigger your action on a `$q.all()`:

```
app.controller('MainCtrl', ['$scope', '$q', function($scope, $q){
    $scope.messages = [];
    var defs = {
        foo: $q.defer(),
        bar: $q.defer()
    };
    $scope.$on('message', function(e, value) {
        $scope.messages.push(value);
        defs[value].resolve();
    });
    $q.all([defs.foo.promise, defs.bar.promise]).then(function() {
        alert('Count: ' + $scope.messages.length); // should not alert until we have all messages!
        defs = null;
    });
}]);
```

Forked fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/GtGB7/1/

Comment: Using `$q` sounds like a great idea, the only problem is I don't know what or even how many children to expect!

Comment: You can still use it and add the deferred objects dynamically to a map or array.

Comment: I can have the child controllers add the deferred objects to an array in the parent controller, but then how do I now that that list is complete?